# Java: cut a String into Properties

Tags: java

I need to extract info from a string and store it in a table, and I now think Properties would be a good choice but unfortunately I cannot finish it. My code is as follows:

```
String st1 = "module name="rootFS1" version="0.1.0" public_cle="0" type="0"";
String st2 = "module name="rootFS2" version="0.1.1" public_cle="1" type="1"";    

StringReader sb1 = new StringReader(st1);
Properties module1 = new Properties();
module.load(sb1);

StringReader sb2 = new StringReader(s2t);
Properties module2 = new Properties();
module.load(sb2);

List<ModuleInfo> modInfoList;

modInfoList.set(1, module1.getProperty("name")); // it doesnot work already here, syntax error 
modInfoList.set(1, module1.getProperty("version"));    
modInfoList.set(1, module1.getProperty("public_cle"));
modInfoList.set(1, module1.getProperty("type")); 

modInfoList.set(2, module2.getProperty("name"));
modInfoList.set(2, module2.getProperty("version"));    
modInfoList.set(2, module2.getProperty("public_cle"));
modInfoList.set(2, module2.getProperty("type"));

return modInfoList;
```

Can anyone give me a better idea for this task? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: share your original code that compilable.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: That doesn't look like the format of properties files. It looks more like the attributes on an XML tag (except that there are no angle brackets and, without escaping the internal double quotes, it doesn't compile).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to insert the return value from `getProperty()` into a `List<ModuleInfo>`, which isn't of the same type.  Try this instead:

```
List<ModuleInfo> modInfoList;

ModuleInfo moduleInfo = new ModuleInfo();
moduleInfo.setName(module, module1.getProperty("name"));
moduleInfo.setVersion(module, module1.getProperty("version"));
moduleInfo.setPublicCle(module, module1.getProperty("public_cle"));
moduleInfo.setType(module, module1.getProperty("type"));
modInfoList.add(moduleInfo);

moduleInfo = new ModuleInfo();
moduleInfo.setName(module, module2.getProperty("name"));
moduleInfo.setVersion(module, module2.getProperty("version"));
moduleInfo.setPublicCle(module, module2.getProperty("public_cle"));
moduleInfo.setType(module, module2.getProperty("type"));
modInfoList.add(moduleInfo);
```

Better yet, pull out the code that creates a ModuleInfo into a helper method that you pass in a Properties object to, and call it twice:

```
List<ModuleInfo> modInfoList;

ModuleInfo moduleInfo = buildModuleInfo(module1);
modInfoList.add(moduleInfo);

moduleInfo = buildModuleInfo(module2);
modInfoList.add(moduleInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your string should use "\n" as delimiter in order for the properties to load

```
    String st1 = "module name=\"rootFS1\" version=\"0.1.0\" public_cle=\"0\" type=\"0\"";
    String[] array = StringUtil.split(st1.split(" ", 2)[1], ' ');

    Properties module1 = new Properties();
    module1.load(new StringReader(StringUtils.join(array, "\n")));

    Map<Integer, String> modInfoList = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    modInfoList.put(1, module1.getProperty("name"));
```

Comment: There is no `set` method on `Map`.